# Number of digits from floating point values in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, floating-point

select name, lat, lng from locations limit 10

What if I want a specific number of digits after the decimal place for lat & lng which happen to be floating point values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X is the number of digits you want:

```
select name, round(lat, X, 1), round(lng, X, 1)
from locations limit 10
```

If you want it to round as well as truncate, take out the 1 parameter of the round function.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you want to get .3

```
select name , lat , lng from locations 
where lat like '%.3' and lng like '%.3'
limit 10
```